# How to create five angle arrow button right after each other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-listview

I am trying to create arrow style button. It has five angle so I cannot stretch the picture to the normal four angle button.

[image]
[image]
Do you have any idea how I can create this button? Is this a Shape or canvas? How they arae created these?

Comment: Hello, 
My main problem is not the strech part. Please see the new attached picture which is explayns the main issue.

Comment: I am still waiting for a good solution, please suggest me someting

Answer (score 1):

How about a background 9 patch, where only the sides are stetchy?

```
 __________
|          \
|__________/

  |------|
stretchy part
```

More info here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: Thanks! 9patch can be  solution but I am not sure because as I see  with this I still ned to stretch this png to a four angle item so the result will be something like this:  http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/218/arrowbutton2.png in this case there is a space between the buttons..  on the mantioned picture there is no space, and that is the tricky part :)

Thanks,
Zsotya